# Multiple textures on one polygon OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, texture-mapping

So I have no idea how I should be doing what I want do so I'll explain as best as I can.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/j65H8.jpg

So imagine that entire image is a 2d square 128x128 and each color I want to apply a texture to that part of the 2d square. Also I want it to stretch as well so Red, Aqua, Green and Purple never stretch in any direction but Pink stretches all directions and then Grey, Yellow, Black and Orange stretch in the longest direction (grey/orange = width expands, yellow/black = height expands). When stretched it should look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJiKv.jpg

Also I am using C++.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing that GL version you are using. If you are using shaders I'm pretty sure you can find a way to mess with the UVs to achieve this.

Comment: Sounds like a [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch).